# How to insert 'place holder' at index in list2 where it misses item from list1?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, compare

These are my two lists:

```
list1=['green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
list2=['yellow', 'blue', 'red']
```

I know for sure `list1` is always bigger than list two.

As you can see `list1` includes 'green' and list2 doesn't.

What line of code do I need that `list2` looks like this:

```
list2=['error', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
```

`list2` should have the string `'error'` right at the index where
it misses the item from `list1`.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah well i tried it more than once first with zip() than with collections both ways i couldn't figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
list1=['green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
list2=['yellow', 'blue', 'red']
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] != list2[i]:
        list2.insert(i,'error')
    
print(list2)
```

Output will look like,

```
['error', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
```